# NotePad++ and JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a web page with within the index.html a slideshow of 8 images. Now if I add these images, and I run it in a random browser it just works perfectly fine, while adding some javascripts to get a beautifull index page with a slideshow, it just does not do anything. I get a white page full of bugs etc. Can some one please tell me what I did do wrong?

```html
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var img1 = new Image()
img1.src ="F:\Thema B\website1\img1.jpg"
var img2 = new Image()
img2.src ="F:\Thema B\website1\img2.jpg"
var img3 = new Image()
img3.src ="F:\Thema B\website1\img3.jpg"
var img4 = new Image()
img4.src ="F:\Thema B\website1\img4.jpg"
var img5 = new Image()
img5.src ="F:\Thema B\website1\img5.jpg"
var img6 = new Image()
img6.src ="F:\Thema B\website1\img6.jpg"
var img7 = new Image()
img7.src ="F:\Thema B\website1\img7.jpg"
var img8 = new Image()
img8.src ="F:\Thema B\website1\img8.jpg"

//-->
</script>
</head>

<body>

<img src="F:\Thema B\website1\img.jpg" name="slide">

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var pic=1
function slides() {
if (!document.images)
return

document.images.slide.src=eval("img"+pic+".src")

if <pic < 8)
pic++

else
pic = 1
setTimeout("slides()",500)
}

slides()
//-->
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your text editor has nothing to do with your issues. For starters, probably not wise to use spaces in filenames. You probably don't want to use "local" paths. Finally, I understand you are a beginner but I think you may need to do a few more tutorials for both HTML and JS. You have some malformed HTML and your JS has a LOT of issues. Check your browser console (F12) and look into those errors.

Answer (score 0):

So...   at first glance, it looks like this line is the issue

```
document.images.slide.src=eval("img"+pic+".src")
```

If you look, you are creating filenames of 'img1.src'.   However, you actually want 'img1.jpg'.

Try this to fix the problem...

```
document.images.slide.src=eval("img"+pic+".jpg")
```

Also, you may likely need to put the full path there as well...   so you may want to use something like

```
document.images.slide.src=eval("F:\Thema B\website1\img"+pic+".jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

1) there is a typo in if line. You typed

```
if <pic < 8)
```

and i think you wanted

```
if (pic < 8)
```

2) reading images from disk. Javascript blocks that due to security reasons